# Core Data and Special Characters in App Name

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I understand that if the app name contains spacing, then when we append the app name to Core Data entity class name, we need to replace the spaces with underscores e.g. `My Game` with `My_Game`.

What if the app name contains exclamation mark i.e. `!` or `?` how does this effect the application name?

Comment: Just as a general rule of thumb, try not to name your projects anything crazy or even remotely interesting. There's a time and place for spaces, exclamation marks, and other fun characters, and that placeis on iTunesConnect when you're setting your app's display name. Spaces aren't that big of a deal, but as you can already see, they can cause complications

Comment: So am I right to say that I do not have to change my project name to be consistent with the eventual app name? For example, if I had registered my app under the name MyApp!, I don't have to change the project name accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluehound made the best point of all, that core data models and project names shouldn't contain crazy characters (which Xcode and MacOS might not deal predictably with).  The place to add your exclamation points and/or those crazy characters is in the app's Info.plist file, which is where the display name is set via the "`CFBundleDisplayName`".

How do to this can be found in [this tutorial](https://kb.applingua.com/2015/10/how-to-localize-app-names/).